# SliverAppBar and title

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver

I have a SliverAppBar, but I want to make it so that when the user starts scrolling, the title becomes like a regular AppBar (centered on top) + before scrolling, it was on the left, not in the center. I don't quite understand how to do this + I want the text style to be different for the two text states, but now it turns out to increase the current through expandedTitleScale, which is not quite the same

```
SliverAppBar(
   pinned: true,
   snap: false,
   floating: false,
   surfaceTintColor: Colors.transparent,
   backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
   collapsedHeight: 50,
   expandedHeight: 150.0,
   automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
   flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
     centerTitle: true,
     title: Text(
        title,
        style: context.appStyles.paragraphP1Medium,
     ),
     expandedTitleScale: 2,
     titlePadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
   ),
),
```

Comment: I think this would help you. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoSliverNavigationBar-class.html

Answer (score 0):

I did this

```
SliverAppBar(
              expandedHeight: _expandedHeight,
              surfaceTintColor: Colors.white,
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              centerTitle: true,
              pinned: true,
              floating: false,
              snap: false,
              elevation: 0,
              title: AnimatedOpacity(
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                opacity: isScrolled ? 1 : 0,
                child: RichText(
                  text: TextSpan(
                    children: [
                      TextSpan(
                        text: widget.title.toLowerCase(),
                        style: context.appStyles.paragraphP1Medium.copyWith(color: context.appColors.base),
                      ),
                      if (widget.subTitle.isNotEmpty)
                        TextSpan(
                          text: ' / ',
                          style: context.appStyles.paragraphP1Medium.copyWith(color: context.appColors.base),
                        ),
                      if (widget.subTitle.isNotEmpty)
                        TextSpan(
                          text: widget.subTitle.toLowerCase(),
                          style: context.appStyles.paragraphP1Medium.copyWith(color: context.appColors.base),
                        ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                background: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                      child: Opacity(
                        opacity: 1 - _opacityTitle,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                          child: RichText(
                            text: TextSpan(
                              children: [
                                TextSpan(
                                  text: widget.title.toLowerCase(),
                                  style: context.appStyles.headingH6.copyWith(color: context.appColors.base),
                                ),
                                if (widget.subTitle.isNotEmpty)
                                  TextSpan(
                                    text: ' / ',
                                    style: context.appStyles.paragraphP1Medium.copyWith(color: context.appColors.base),
                                  ),
                                if (widget.subTitle.isNotEmpty)
                                  TextSpan(
                                    text: widget.subTitle.toLowerCase(),
                                    style: context.appStyles.paragraphP1Medium.copyWith(color: context.appColors.base),
                                  ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                      child: Container(
                        height: 56,
                        color: context.appColors.inverse,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

```
void _listenToScrollChange() {
    if (controller.offset >= 44.0) {
      _expandedHeight = 44;
      _opacityTitle = 1;
      setState(() {
        isScrolled = true;
      });
    } else {
      _expandedHeight = 44 + (49 - controller.offset);
      if (_expandedHeight >= 93) _expandedHeight = 93;
      _opacityTitle = 1 - ((_expandedHeight - 49) / 40);
      if (_opacityTitle <= 0 ) _opacityTitle = 0;
      if (_opacityTitle > 1) _opacityTitle = 1;
      setState(() {
        isScrolled = false;
      });
    }
  }
```